# Query failed Time out : can anyone see any way to make this more efficient so it doesn't time out? my automation is in error because of my query

Tags: mysql, sql, automation, salesforce, salesforce-marketing-cloud

```
SELECT 
    Concat('Guest-',NEWID()) AS SubscriberKey,
    EmailAddress,
    OrderNumber,
    'True' as 'Optin',
    'Guest' as 'TypeContact',
    OrderDate as 'Date-Inscription',
    'False' as 'BackInStock'
FROM [OrderConfirmation-NoXML]
WHERE EmailAddress NOT IN (SELECT EmailAddress FROM MC_Contacts_Client)
```

Comment: have index on EmailAddress ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have you tried using not exists rather than not in ?

Comment: Your question might attract more attention at https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/. The main stackoverflow is very coding-related whereas on the SF site Admins and Marketing Cloud specialists can ask about non-coding things too and get better responses.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Concat('Guest-',NEWID()) AS SubscriberKey, 
       EmailAddress, OrderNumber, 'True' as 'Optin', 
       'Guest' as 'TypeContact', OrderDate as 'Date-Inscription', 
      'False' as 'BackInStock' 
       FROM [OrderConfirmation-NoXML] T
       WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM MC_Contacts_Client M WHERE   T.EmailAddress=M.EmailAddress )
```

Could you please try this?